# Inserting an object's id into a table after creating the object

Tags: jquery, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create an Order that has a list of Products. For this I display all the products available and using a checkbox input and some jQuery and ajax I managed to send all my data to the Test action inside my Orders controller

Test action

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Test(string dest_in, string date_in, string cost_in, List<int> list_in)
        {

            int count = list_in.Count;
            var ord_dest = dest_in;
            var ord_dest1 = date_in;
            var ord_dest2 = cost_in;
            var lis2 = list_in;
        }
```

And the jQuery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddProduct() {
        var list = new Array();
        var dest = document.getElementById("model_dest").value;
        var date = document.getElementById("model_date").value;
        var cost = document.getElementById("model_cost").value;
        alert(dest);
        alert(date);
        alert(cost);
        $.each($("#products input[type=checkbox]:checked"),
            function (index, data) {
                var idk1 = $(this).val();
                var idk2 = $(this).attr('value');
                list.push(idk1);
                alert(idk1 + ' ' + idk2);
            });
        alert(list.length);

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Test", "Orders")",
             data: ({
                 dest_in: dest,
                 date_in: date,
                 cost_in: cost,
                 list_in: list
             }),
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The Test function is not complete. I used it just to test my jQuery code, and inside it I want to create the new Order but..

The problem I'm facing now is that since Order Product is in many-to-many relationship I need to use a OrdProd table to store what products are in what order. But how can I get my newly created Order's id to insert it in OrdProd.

PS
id column inside Order is of type Identity

**EDIT**
All other columns in order can be duplicated so I can't perform a select on all the other atributs

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you want to do this:

- Begin an SQL *transaction.*
- Insert the product, obtaining its ID.
- Update the other table with that ID.
- `COMMIT` the transaction.

Other users will see the database actually change only when you `COMMIT`, and they will see everything change at once.

Comment: But how to I obtain its ID?

Answer (score 0):

The command is:

_context.Products.FromSqlRaw("Select * from Product where id = ident_current('Product')").ToList();

where:

_context is the AppDbContext

Products is the table in witch I want to search for last item inserted

FrowmSqlRaw its a function to perform raw queries fromMicrosoft.EntityFrameworkCore

**AND** last the id of the last item inserted in Product table is returned by **ident_current('Product')**